# Passing data to an unknown variable

Tags: c#, c++

I am developing a project that uses serial communication to interface between a micro-controller and my computer.  I want to be able to pass what variable I want to change as well as the data to be assigned to the variable.  Would this instance require use of a pointer or an "address-of-operator"?

Function

```
void xyz(int &variable, int data){
    &variable = data;
}
```

In theory...

```
int x = 0;
xyz(&x, 1)
```

x now equals 1.

Comment: Note: If I am completely wrong with my theory.  Please give some suggestion or resources on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, what you're asking about is the concept of [references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science)).

C doesn't have a formal notion of reference types, so, what you do in C is take address and use pointers.  In C:

```
void xyz ( int *variable, int data ) {
    *variable = data;
}

int x = 0;
xyz ( &x, 1 );
```

C++ has a formal notion of reference types, so there you can use them as such:

```
void xyz ( int &variable, int data ) {
    variable = data;
}

int x = 0;
xyz ( x, 1 );
```

*Note that because C++ has reference **types**, they can be used for formal parameters, and also local variables, instance members (fields), etc..*

C++ also has pointers so the above C example will work in C++, though for these purposes, the reference types are preferred (for one, they preclude pointer arithmetic).

C# doesn't have a formal notion of reference types, however, has a formal notion of [`out` parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)#Output_parameters), so in C#:

```
void xyz ( out int variable, int data ) {
    variable = data;
}

int x = 0;
xyz ( out x, 1 );
```

Note that C# also has pointers; however, to use them you need to use the `unsafe` keyword.

*Also note that in C#, all variables of object type are references: this includes local variables, formal parameters, and instance variables (fields).  Declaring a variable of object type does not create or allocate an object, only execution of a `new` expression does that (which, of course, we can put that for a variable's initializer).  (Declarations themselves reserve space for the reference, an initializer, if provided, provides the initial value for the reference.)*

*In C# (by the default parameter mode of `in`), expressions of all kinds are passed from caller to callee by value (as if assigned), so assignment to the formal parameter itself, from within the callee, would not effect the caller's variables (unless using a `ref` or `out`).  So, object types are references that are passed by value with the default `in`.*

*While changes to the formal parameter are only visible to the caller if using `ref` or `out`, changes to the referenced objects themselves are visible to the caller regardless of the parameter passing mode.*

*For C#, this applies to class instances but not struct instances as struct variables actually are values.  (Declaring a struct variable directly creates storage for the struct.)  Structs are also passed by value; changes to structs in the callee are not reflected back to the caller (unless using `ref` or `out`).*

Comment: Thank you, Your answer provided much needed clarification.